# Why does the following not logging anything to the console?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose I already have a file called blog.txt containing some text. I am first reading the content from it and logging it to the console. Afterwards I need to replace the content of the file. But when I am running the following code, the console logs nothing. Why is that?

```
const fs = require('fs')

fs.readFile('./blog.txt', (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err.message)
  } else
    console.log(data.toString())
})

fs.writeFile('./blog.txt', "yello", () => {})
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the nodejs output?

Comment: showing no errors

Comment: Set `console.log` before `fs.readFile` and before `if(err)`. We need to know if fs.readFile even fires callback

Comment: You aren't "first reading and logging" it, you're *starting* a read/log process, and *immediately* starting a `writeFile`. If you want to *finish* reading the file before writing then you should either use `readFileSync` or do the write in the read handler

Comment: If you log `fs.readFile('./blog.txt')`, what does it output?

Comment: @DaveNewton, well, althought you are right, this does not explain why there is no console output

Comment: Are you running this file directly from the command line such as `node blog.js`?

Comment: @AidOnline01 Didn't say it did :) Although it trivially *could*, since `writeFile` creates a new file if the file exists, and it's buffered.

Comment: @evolutionxbox An empty line

Comment: @jfriend00 using nodemon

Comment: @DaveNewton So the reading and overwriting happens simultaneously?

Comment: I'd suggest first running your code directly from the command line without other stuff in the way.   Go to the basics.  As others have pointed out, the code is also wrong.  If you put logging in the `fs.writeFile()` callback and put logging before and after everything, you should get some logging.  If not, then your code is not even running because of the way you started it.  FYI, this is all elemental debugging steps that you should be doing before you come here as it's a really valuable skill.

Comment: @user16261114 It *could* be happening *effectively* simultaneously (but not *actually* simultaneously). You're starting an async operation then *immediately* doing something with the target of that async operation; while the behavior *may* be defined, IMO it's a Much Better Idea to make things explicit.

Comment: @DaveNewton  Since both readFile and writeFile are asynchronous and readFile is called first, it should be executed first, right?

Comment: `readFile` *is* called first--that doesn't mean it has *read* anything (let alone called its callback) before you call `writeFile`.

Comment: To test out @DaveNewton hypothesis (which I strongly suspect is the culprit) try commenting out the writefile line and seeing what happens with your code. Do you get console output now?

Comment: Not normal, you may a pb with your Node, can you test on a other host (VM) and than reinsall Node

Comment: @DaveNewton - Both readFile and writeFile are multiple asynchronous step processes.  They open the file, read/write from it and close it as separate asynchronous steps so those steps will get interleaved.  What likely happens is readFile initiates opening it for reading, then writeFile initiates opening it for writing (by truncating its existing contents).  That either generates an error which is silently ignored in this code or sets up a failure in the future reads/writes.  Anyway, the code is a mess and should NEVER be written this way.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, I know.